# Kernel panic installing CentOS7 guest on CentOS7 host

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, kernel-panic, centos7

I'm trying to install a CentOS 7 guest as a guest on CentOS 7 KVM host but keep getting a Kernel panic, and it seems to happen at the exact same spot every time. I've even tried installing a CentOS 6 guest but get a kernel panic on that as well.

There are five guests (all CentOS 6) running on the host already although all were moved from another host. I've updated the host with the latest updates, only the standard repos and packages are installed but still no luck.

Hopefully someone can see what I'm doing wrong or what may be causing the kernel panic.

The processor is an Intel Core i3-4130, the motherboard a Gigabyte Z97P-D3, 16GB RAM.

The install script:

```
$IMGNAME=server
$KICKSTART=kickstart.cfg
$DISKSIZE=40

virt-install \
--name $IMGNAME \
--ram 1024 \
--cpu host \
--vcpus 1 \
--network bridge:bridge0 \
--nographics \
--os-type=linux \
--location $IMGFILE \
--os-variant=rhel7 \
--initrd-inject=../kickstarts/$KICKSTART \
--extra-args="ks=file:/$KICKSTART text utf8 console=ttyS0,115200 modprobe.blacklist=cnic,bnx2i" \
--disk path=/data/kvm/images/$IMGNAME.img,size=$DISKSIZE,bus=virtio --force \
--noreboot
```

The kickstart file:

```
install
lang en_US.UTF-8
keyboard is-latin1
timezone Europe/Stockholm
auth --useshadow --enablemd5
selinux --disabled
firewall --disabled
services --enabled=NetworkManager,sshd
eula --agreed
network --onboot=on --bootproto=dhcp
reboot
firstboot --disable

bootloader --location=mbr
zerombr
clearpart --all --initlabel
part swap --asprimary --fstype="swap" --size=1024
part /boot --fstype xfs --size=500
part pv.01 --size=1 --grow
volgroup rootvg01 pv.01
logvol / --fstype xfs --name=lv01 --vgname=rootvg01 --size=1 --grow

rootpw change

repo --name=base --baseurl=http://mirror.cogentco.com/pub/linux/centos/7/os/x86_64/
url --url="http://mirror.cogentco.com/pub/linux/centos/7/os/x86_64/"

%packages --nobase --ignoremissing
@core
%end
```

This is the output from the install:

```
Welcome to CentOS Linux 7 (Core) dracut-033-161.el7 (Initramfs)!

[    2.736860] systemd[1]: No hostname configured.
[    2.737246] systemd[1]: Set hostname to .
[    2.737665] systemd[1]: Initializing machine ID from KVM UUID.
[    2.749598] systemd[1]: Starting -.slice.
[  OK  ] Created slice -.slice.
[    2.750675] systemd[1]: Created slice -.slice.
[    2.751215] systemd[1]: Starting System Slice.
[  OK  ] Created slice System Slice.
[    2.752258] systemd[1]: Created slice System Slice.
[    2.752680] systemd[1]: Starting Slices.
[  OK  ] Reached target Slices.
[    2.753631] systemd[1]: Reached target Slices.
[    2.754078] systemd[1]: Starting Timers.
[  OK  ] Reached target Timers.
[    2.754931] systemd[1]: Reached target Timers.
[    2.755392] systemd[1]: Starting Encrypted Volumes.
[  OK  ] Reached target Encrypted Volumes.
[    2.756459] systemd[1]: Reached target Encrypted Volumes.
[    2.756919] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Socket.
[  OK  ] Listening on Journal Socket.
[    2.757951] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket.
[    2.758533] systemd[1]: Starting dracut cmdline hook...
         Starting dracut cmdline hook...
[    2.759759] systemd[1]: Started Load Kernel Modules.
[    2.760270] systemd[1]: Starting Setup Virtual Console...
         Starting Setup Virtual Console...
[    2.761474] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Service...
         Starting Journal Service...
[  OK  ] Started Journal Service.
[    2.764043] systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.
[  OK  ] Listening on udev Kernel Socket.
[  OK  ] Listening on udev Control Socket.
[  OK  ] Reached target Sockets.
         [    2.772027] systemd-journald[75]: Vacuuming done, freed 0 bytes
Starting Create list of required static device nodes...rrent kernel...
         Starting Apply Kernel Variables...
         Starting Device-Mapper Multipath Device Controller...
[  OK  ] Reached target Swap.
[  OK  ] Reached target Local File Systems.
[    2.789576] device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
[  OK  ] Started Setup Virtual Console.
[  OK  ] Started Apply Kernel Variables.
[    2.793545] device-mapper: ioctl: 4.27.0-ioctl (2013-10-30) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
[  OK  ] Started Create list of required static device nodes ...current kernel.
         Starting Create static device nodes in /dev...
[    2.804180] device-mapper: multipath: version 1.6.0 loaded
[  OK  ] Started Create static device nodes in /dev.
[  OK  ] Started Device-Mapper Multipath Device Controller.
[    2.841315] BIOS EDD facility v0.16 2004-Jun-25, 1 devices found
[    3.012027] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 2 using uhci_hcd
[    3.163353] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0627, idProduct=0001
[    3.163885] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=3, SerialNumber=5
[    3.164473] usb 1-1: Product: QEMU USB Tablet
[    3.164899] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: QEMU
[    3.165211] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 42
[    3.175931] input: QEMU QEMU USB Tablet as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/input/input2
[    3.176893] hid-generic 0003:0627:0001.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v0.01 Pointer [QEMU QEMU USB Tablet] on usb-0000:00:01.2-1/input0
[  OK  ] Started dracut cmdline hook.
         Starting dracut pre-udev hook...
[    3.234818] squashfs: version 4.0 (2009/01/31) Phillip Lougher
[    3.237856] Loading iSCSI transport class v2.0-870.
[    3.240677] iscsi: registered transport (tcp)
[    3.265235] FDC 0 is a S82078B
[    3.268180] No iBFT detected.
[    3.269771] md: raid0 personality registered for level 0
[    3.272109] md: raid1 personality registered for level 1
[    3.273878] async_tx: api initialized (async)
[    3.274822] xor: measuring software checksum speed
[    3.285006]    prefetch64-sse: 17100.000 MB/sec
[    3.295006]    generic_sse: 15864.000 MB/sec
[    3.295353] xor: using function: prefetch64-sse (17100.000 MB/sec)
[    3.314012] raid6: sse2x1   10269 MB/s
[    3.331009] raid6: sse2x2   12937 MB/s
[    3.348012] raid6: sse2x4   15062 MB/s
[    3.349017] invalid opcode: 0000 [#1] SMP 
[    3.349348] Modules linked in: raid6_pq(+) async_xor xor async_tx raid1 raid0 iscsi_ibft iscsi_boot_sysfs floppy iscsi_tcp libiscsi_tcp libiscsi scsi_transport_iscsi squashfs cramfs edd dm_multipath dm_mod
[    3.350004] CPU: 0 PID: 363 Comm: modprobe Not tainted 3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64 #1
[    3.350004] Hardware name: Red Hat KVM, BIOS 0.5.1 01/01/2011
[    3.350004] task: ffff88003320ad80 ti: ffff88003f4ba000 task.ti: ffff88003f4ba000
[    3.350004] RIP: 0010:[]  [] raid6_avx21_gen_syndrome+0x4a/0x160 [raid6_pq]
[    3.350004] RSP: 0018:ffff88003f4bbc58  EFLAGS: 00010246
[    3.350004] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff88003f4bbca0 RCX: ffff88003320ad80
[    3.350004] RDX: ffff88003f4bbfd8 RSI: 0000000000000080 RDI: 0000000000000012
[    3.350004] RBP: ffff88003f4bbc88 R08: 0000000000000082 R09: 00000000000001b4
[    3.350004] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: ffff88003f4bb9ae R12: 0000000000001000
[    3.350004] R13: ffff88003f4fe000 R14: ffff88003f4ff000 R15: 0000000000000012
[    3.350004] FS:  00007f35b9a15740(0000) GS:ffff88003da00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[    3.350004] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[    3.350004] CR2: 00007fd4f9592038 CR3: 0000000033213000 CR4: 00000000001006f0
[    3.350004] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
[    3.350004] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000ffff0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
[    3.350004] Stack:
[    3.350004]  0000000000000080 ffffffffa00bc238 ffffffffa00ce720 ffff88003f4fe000
[    3.350004]  0000000000000f10 00000000fffb7935 ffff88003f4bbd60 ffffffffa00d3108
[    3.350004]  0000000000000000 ffffffffa00be600 ffffffffa00bf600 ffffffffa00c0600
[    3.350004] Call Trace:
[    3.350004]  [] init_module+0x108/0x1000 [raid6_pq]
[    3.350004]  [] ? 0xffffffffa00d2fff
[    3.350004]  [] do_one_initcall+0xe2/0x190
[    3.350004]  [] load_module+0x129b/0x1a90
[    3.350004]  [] ? ddebug_proc_write+0xf0/0xf0
[    3.350004]  [] ? copy_module_from_fd.isra.43+0x53/0x150
[    3.350004]  [] SyS_finit_module+0xa6/0xd0
[    3.350004]  [] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
[    3.350004] Code: 00 00 00 00 53 48 89 d3 48 83 ec 08 48 89 75 d0 4c 8b 2c c2 4c 8b 74 32 08 e8 83 00 f6 e0 84 c0 0f 84 f1 00 00 00 e8 66 01 f6 e0  fd 6f 05 9e 2a 01 00 c5 e5 ef db 4d 85 e4 0f 84 c0 00 00 00 
[    3.350004] RIP  [] raid6_avx21_gen_syndrome+0x4a/0x160 [raid6_pq]
[    3.350004]  RSP 
[    3.369069] ---[ end trace e0b9f2a670432dc0 ]---
[    3.369464] Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception
```

Comment: What is the physical CPU in the server?

Comment: Ah, should have thought of including that info! It's an Intel Core i3-4130, the motherboard is a Gigabyte Z97P-D3. Updating the question with this as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved this with a hint from **drk** in the official CentOS forums, the problem lay with the CPU settings, simply remove the setting and use the default CPU setting did the trick. Here's what worked for me in the end:

```
IMGNAME=server
KICKSTART=kickstart.cfg
DISKSIZE=40

virt-install \
--name $IMGNAME \
--ram 1024 \
--vcpus 1 \
--network bridge:bridge0 \
--nographics \
--os-type=linux \
--location=$IMGFILE \
--os-variant=rhel7 \
--initrd-inject=../kickstarts/$KICKSTART \
--extra-args="inst.ks=file:/$KICKSTART text utf8 mce=ignore_ce console=ttyS0,115200 modprobe.blacklist=cnic,bnx2i" \
--disk path=/data/kvm/images/$IMGNAME.img,size=$DISKSIZE,bus=virtio --force \
--noreboot
```

and the kickstart file:

```
install
lang en_US.UTF-8
keyboard is-latin1
timezone Europe/Stockholm
auth --useshadow --enablemd5
selinux --disabled
firewall --disabled
services --enabled=NetworkManager,sshd
eula --agreed
network --onboot=on --bootproto=dhcp
reboot
firstboot --disable

bootloader --location=mbr
zerombr
clearpart --all --initlabel
part swap --asprimary --fstype="swap" --size=1024
part /boot --fstype xfs --size=500
part pv.01 --size=1 --grow
volgroup rootvg01 pv.01
logvol / --fstype xfs --name=lv01 --vgname=rootvg01 --size=1 --grow

rootpw change

# repo --name=base --baseurl=http://ftp.sunet.se/pub/Linux/distributions/centos/7.0.1406/isos/x86_64
# url --url=http://ftp.sunet.se/pub/Linux/distributions/centos/7.0.1406/isos/x86_64

%packages
@core
%end
```